# Describing the relation $R$ in the $xy$-plane and finding $R[A]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question saying:

> If $R = \{ (x,y) | x<y\}$ describe $R$ in the $xy$-plane. Treating $R$ as a relation, what is $R[A]$ if $A= \{ 3,8,2,4,5\}$

Am i right in describing $R$ as all pairs $(x,y)$ to the left of the line $y=x$?

And would it be correct to say $R[A] = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} | \ y > 2\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly! Your answers look good to me.